# How to escape square brackets in a ls output

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I'm experiencing some problems to escape square brackets in any file name.

I need to compare two list. The ls output is the first list and the second is the ARQ02.

```
#!/bin/bash  

exec 3< <(ls /home/lint)  

while read arq <&3; do  
 var=`grep -e "$arq" ARQ02`  
    if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] ; then  
     echo "$arq" >> result  
    fi  
done  

exec 3<&-
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: what is `ARQ02`? it seems to me a file. so are you saying just to see if your files in certain folder happen to be a subset of the files listed in another file? there are a number of common mistakes you are making here in such short script already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you must **instruct `grep` to interpret the search term as a *literal*** rather than a regular expression, using the **`-F` option**:

```
var=$(grep -Fe "$arq" ARQ02)
```

That way, any regex metacharacters that happen to be in the output from `ls /home/lint` - such as `[` and `]` - will still be treated as *literals* and won't break the `grep` invocation.

That said, it looks like your **command could be streamlined**, such as by **using the output from `ls /home/lint` *directly* as the set of search strings to pass to `grep` *at once***, using the **`-f` option**:

```
grep -Ff <(ls /home/lint) ARQ02 > result
```

`<(...)` is a so-called [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), which, simply put, presents the output from a command as if it were a (temporary) *file*, which is what `-f` expects: a file containing the search terms for `grep`.

---

Alternatively, if:

- the lines of `ARQ02` contain *only* filenames that *fully* match (some of) the filenames in the output from `ls /home/lint`, and
- you don't mind *sorting* or want to sort the matches stored in `result`,

consider [HuStmpHrrr's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40252421/45375).

Answer (score 2):

i have to assume my interpretation is correct. based on that, i can raise a oneliner easily solve your solution. there are 2 assumption i need to make here: your file name doesn't contain carriage return and you are using modern bash:

```
comm -23 <(printf "%s\n" * | sort) <(sort ARQ02)
```

in bash `<()` emits a subshell and pipe the stdout as a file. `comm` is the command to compute difference of 2 input stream.

to explain in details,

```
comm
-23 # suppress files unique in ARQ02 and files in common
<(printf "%s\n" * | # print all the files in local folder with new line breaker
   sort) # sort them
<(sort ARQ02)
```

it's necessary to sort as `comm` only compare incrementally.